# Looking for graded vocabulary lists

Tags: vocabulary, reference-request, proficiency-test

When I was learning English, I was greatly helped by a series of vocabulary lists, *graded* from 1st to 12th grade, and consisting of words that students in those grades were supposed to master<sup>1</sup>.  After learning that vocabulary, I moved on to SAT and GRE prep books, for college-level and graduate-school-level vocabulary.

I'm looking for a similar *graded* approach to German vocabulary.

I am sure that something like this must exist for German, but I have not hit upon the right keywords and/or search strategy to find it.  Any pointers would be appreciated.

---

I should point out that I am *not* interested in lists directed at learners of German as a second language.  I am (primarily) interested in lists whose target audience consists of (school- and college-age) native speakers of German.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>I found these lists by chance, as a supplement in a dictionary.  This all happened decades before Google.</sup>

Comment: German children learn reading from a **Lesebuch** in their German classes. Usually there is one per school grade 1-4, with texts written for the increasing vocabulary and grammar experience.

Comment: @Janka: Thanks for your comment.  If you were to search for something approximating what I'm asking about, what keywords (in German, of course) would you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for:

*Wortschatz*, *Grundwortschatz* or *Basiswortschatz*.

These terms are used in the context of educating German at school, usually at primary school.

[Here](https://bildungsserver.berlin-brandenburg.de/fileadmin/bbb/unterricht/faecher/sprachen/deutsch/Grundschule/2011_11_25_GWS_1_WEB.pdf) is an example from Brandenburg and Berlin with the *Grundwortschatz* for grades 1 and 2 as well as 3 and 4.
[This](https://www.bildung-mv.de/export/sites/bildungsserver/downloads/Handreichung-Mindestwortschatz.pdf) document lists the *Mindestwortschatz* for the primary school in Mecklenburg-Vorpommern.
Hamburg offers a [digital version](http://li.hamburg.de/basiswortschatz/) of its *Basiswortschatz* for primary schools.

I am not aware of such lists for elder pupils.

Edit: New links to Grundwortschatz Berlin grade [1 and 2](https://bildungsserver.berlin-brandenburg.de/fileadmin/bbb/rlp-online/Teil_C/Deutsch/Materialien/Grundwortschatz_Berlin_1_und_2_Jahrgangsstufe_2020.pdf) and grade [3 and 4](https://bildungsserver.berlin-brandenburg.de/fileadmin/bbb/rlp-online/Teil_C/Deutsch/Materialien/Grundwortschatz_Berlin_3_und_4_Jahrgangsstufe_2020.pdf)

Comment: The Brandenburg PDF is no longer on-line, there is an [archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20180219023405/https://bildungsserver.berlin-brandenburg.de/fileadmin/bbb/unterricht/faecher/sprachen/deutsch/Grundschule/2011_11_25_GWS_1_WEB.pdf) though.

Comment: @RDBury I've added the current pdfs for Berlin

Comment: Apparently the earlier one is meant for teachers while the new ones are meant for students. There's nothing wrong with that, since both formats are useful, but I thought it was worth pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

While I understand, that this is not what you ask for, others coming across the question may be interested:

I never heard something of something corresponding to your 12 levels. The closest I'm aware of are the word lists of the [language proficiency levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_European_Framework_of_Reference_for_Languages), one example is [B1-Liste des Goethe-Instituts](http://www.goethe.de/lhr/pro/daz/dfz/dtz_Wortliste.pdf).

For books intended for children there are publisher specific classification schemes for the age range, which is somehow related, but not directly resulting in word lists.

Comment: My problem with CEFR is that it seems to be heavily biased for travelers. For example *treten* is a very common word not on the A1 (Goethe) list, but *ankreuzen* is an uncommon word that is. If you're interest is primarily to watch a Netflix show in German then you're much better off learning *treten* than *ankreuzen*, unless it's a very, very boring show.